# IIS is not working in windows 8.1 Pro

Tags: iis, windows-8.1, iis-8.5

I have formatted and re installed new windows 8.1 and installed and enabled the IIS from program and features through the windows component and installed correctly but when I tried to run the localhost to check IIS then its not working and nothing display on the page. There is no any error shows just white blank page. If anybody can help to resolved this issue then that would be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are talking about `Static HTML` pages? What all `components` did you install along with `IIS`? Make sure you have `StaticFileModule` installed